# Ever increasing physical memory for a Spark application in YARN

Tags: java, hadoop, memory, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a Spark application in YARN having two executors with Xms/Xmx as 32 GB and spark.yarn.excutor.memoryOverhead as 6 GB.

I am seeing that the application's physical memory is ever increasing and finally gets killed by the node manager:

```
2015-07-25 15:07:05,354 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Container [pid=10508,containerID=container_1437828324746_0002_01_000003] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 38.0 GB of 38 GB physical memory used; 39.5 GB of 152 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1437828324746_0002_01_000003 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 10508 9563 10508 10508 (bash) 0 0 9433088 314 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/default/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms32768m -Xmx32768m  -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-executor.properties -XX:MetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyOutputInterval=1  -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:GCLogFileSize=500M -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3500M -XX:NewRatio=3 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=36082 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=100M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=256m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/yarn/datanode/nm-local-dir/usercache/admin/appcache/application_1437828324746_0002/container_1437828324746_0002_01_000003/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=43354' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1437828324746_0002/container_1437828324746_0002_01_000003 org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend akka.tcp://sparkDriver@nn1:43354/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler 1 dn3 6 application_1437828324746_0002 1> /opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1437828324746_0002/container_1437828324746_0002_01_000003/stdout 2> /opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1437828324746_0002/container_1437828324746_0002_01_000003/stderr
```

I diabled YARN's parameter "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled" and noticed that physical memory usage went till 40 GB.

I checked the total RSS in `/proc/pid/smaps`, and it was same value as physical memory reported by Yarn and seen in top command.

I checked that it's not a problem with the heap, but something is increasing in off heap/ native memory. I used tools like Visual VM, but didn't find anything that's increasing there. MaxDirectMmeory also didn't exceed 600 MB. Peak number of active threads was 70-80 and thread stack size didn't exceed 100 MB. MetaspaceSize was around 60-70 MB.

FYI, I am on Spark 1.2 and Hadoop 2.4.0 and my Spark application is based on Spark SQL and it's an HDFS read/write intensive application and caches data in Spark SQL's in-memory caching.

Where should I look to debug memory leak or is there a tool already there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I was able to get rid of the issue. The issue was that the compressors created in Spark SQL's parquet write path weren't getting recycled and hence, my executors were creating a brand new compressor (from native memory) for every parquet write file and thus exhausting the physical memory limits.

I had opened the following bug in Parquet Jira and have raised the PR for same :-

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-353

This fixed the memory issue at my end.

P.S. - You will see this problem only in a Parquet write intensive application.

Comment: How did you found that it was Parquet? We have a similar issue (but we are not using parquet) and we are not sure how to find the culprit

Comment: We had a similar (off heap) OOM issue that was pretty nasty to track down.  Turned out it was the Hadoop native libs for gzip output (hadoop.native.lib).  We now do this at start up, and while performance isn't as good, the leak is gone: JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration()); jobConf.setBoolean("hadoop.native.lib", false);