# How is virtual memory calculated in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am using Spark on Hadoop and want to know how Spark allocates the virtual memory to executor.

As per YARN vmem-pmem, it gives 2.1 times virtual memory to the container.

Hence - if XMX is 1 GB then --> 1 GB * 2.1 = 2.1 GB is allocated to the container.

How does it work on Spark? And is the below statement is correct?

If I give Executor memory = 1 GB then,

Total virtual memory = 1 GB * 2.1 * spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead. Is this true?

If not, then how is virtual memory for an executor calculated in Spark?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005643/container-is-running-beyond-memory-limits. I hope this will help you

Comment: can you please check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

For Spark executor resources, yarn-client and yarn-cluster modes use the same configurations:

[image]

In spark-defaults.conf, spark.executor.memory is set to 2 GB.

I got this from: *[Resource Allocation Configuration for Spark on YARN](https://www.mapr.com/blog/resource-allocation-configuration-spark-yarn)*

Comment: As per http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html executorMemory * 0.10, with minimum of 384. I want to know which one is correct.  But the main question that I have is whether in case of SPARK does YARN uses vmem-pmem (default 2.1) to calculate the virtual memory and then adds the overhead to that memory? In such case for 1GB of memory to SPARK container- the total virtual memory becomes 1 * 2.1 * overhead? Is this statement correct?

Comment: As per the problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646679/ever-increasing-physical-memory-for-a-spark-application-in-yarn 

Configurations are: 

spark.executor.memory = 32 GB spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead = 6 GB

How come virtual memory is calculated as 152 GB(as per the error message)?

Is it (32 + 6) * 4 = 152 where 4 is yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio?